# Why is my function not reaching this forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to add to my firestore database when a user signs up, but for some reason the code simply isn't reaching the forEach loop. I've tried adding a bunch of logging as you can see below. The logs show that it reached `console.log('_createUser: 1.1');` but it never reaches `console.log('_createUser: 2');`. Why isn't it doing the forEach loop?

Note - the function finishes with status code 200.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
// import { error } from 'firebase-functions/lib/logger';
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log('_createUser: ');
  const uid = context?.auth?.uid;
  if (uid) {
    const username = data.user;
    const email = data.email;
    console.log('_createUser: 1');
    //Check to see if that username already exists
    const qData = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get();
    console.log('_createUser: 1.1');
    qData.forEach(doc => {
      console.log('_createUser: 2');
      const otherUsername = doc.get('username').toString();      
      if (otherUsername) {
        console.log('_createUser: Username is already in use.');
        return 'Username is already in use.'
      }
      else {
        console.log('_createUser: 3');
        //Create collection for this user's friends list
        const friendsColl = 'friends_' + uid;
        const friendsDoc = admin.firestore().collection(friendsColl).doc();
        friendsDoc.set({
          //Forces the collection to exist
          exists: 1, 

          //Other useful data
          createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          ownerUsername: username,
          ownerUID: uid, //
          rowType: 'B', //N = normal, B = backend (created for server side reasons)
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
        console.log('_createUser: 4');
        const userDoc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid); // use uid as document ID
        userDoc.set({
          createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          username: username,
          email: email,
          stat: 1, //0 = banned, 1 = normal
          uid: uid,
          friendsColl: friendsColl,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
        return console.log('_createUser_finished');
      };
    });    
  }
  else {
    return console.log('_createUser_Error: User is not authorized');
  };
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Also, log the array and make sure it's not empty

Comment: @AluanHaddad no errors in the console. I guess I should mention that `const qData = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get();` is going to return no rows because the username I'm trying to sign up with definitely doesn't exist. Before, I had it set so that it was checking to see if `qData` existed, but this was returning true so I simply removed it.

Answer (score 3):

The `qData` object is a `QuerySnapshot`. The documents returned by the query can be accessed from the `docs` property. So, you need to update `qData.forEach(doc => {` to `qData.docs.forEach(doc => {`.

Just curious, why not use a Firebase Auth trigger function for this? You can write a function that would run each time a user is created, without having to do anything on your end. Take a look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions?authuser=0).

Comment: Is there a difference doing it like this vs using an auth trigger?

Comment: Practically you could achieve the same result with either solution. But using an auth trigger makes more sense, since you want to run this function whenever a user signs up. You wouldn't have to check for authorization nor would you use a Firestore read. I think the main benefit would be that it'll run automatically instead of relying on being invoked externally.

Comment: Ah, I'm using the client side firebase.auth to safely pass the email and password to the server. I'm not sure how to encrypt this information before passing to the backend to run the auth trigger there.

Comment: You don't need to worry about authentication for trigger functions. They are fully insulated from the client. If you rewrite this onCall function as a trigger function, it will not have the first `if` check, and you will get the user details from the UserRecord object passed to the handler (so no Firestore read either).

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't resolve Promise. Use this format.

```js
qData.then(snap => {
  snap.forEach(doc=>{
  ...
  })
})
```

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
// import { error } from 'firebase-functions/lib/logger';
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log('_createUser: ');
  const uid = context?.auth?.uid;
  if (!uid) {
    console.log('_createUser_Error: User is not authorized');
    return 
  }
  const username = data.user;
  const email = data.email;
  console.log('_createUser: 1');
  //Check to see if that username already exists
  const qData = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get();
  console.log('_createUser: 1.1');
  qData.then(snapShot => {
    snapShot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log('_createUser: 2');
      const otherUsername = doc.get('username').toString();      
      if (otherUsername) {
        console.log('_createUser: Username is already in use.');
        return 'Username is already in use.'
      }
      else {
        console.log('_createUser: 3');
        //Create collection for this user's friends list
        const friendsColl = 'friends_' + uid;
        const friendsDoc = admin.firestore().collection(friendsColl).doc();
        friendsDoc.set({
          //Forces the collection to exist
          exists: 1, 

          //Other useful data
          createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          ownerUsername: username,
          ownerUID: uid, //
          rowType: 'B', //N = normal, B = backend (created for server side reasons)
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
        console.log('_createUser: 4');
        const userDoc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid); // use uid as document ID
        userDoc.set({
          createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          username: username,
          email: email,
          stat: 1, //0 = banned, 1 = normal
          uid: uid,
          friendsColl: friendsColl,
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
        return console.log('_createUser_finished');
      };
    })
  })
})
```